# What is "float_t" for?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Should I be using float_t instead of float?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're additional types requires by the C standard. They're intended to be "the implementation's most efficient types at least as wide as float and double, respectively." The question of what you *should* be doing is a matter of opinion, I suppose, but I've never seen them used in any Cocoa code (and probably not even any C code) if that means anything to you.

Comment: It's just that code sense autocompletes it when typing method names. What's up with that?

Comment: They are not the "most efficient". They're the type with excess precision that `FLOAT_EVAL_METHOD` refers to and which may be used in computing intermediate results. You generally should not use them at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should be using CGFloat.